# UIView Above Keyboard not Displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextview

Im using the [Apple KeyBoardAccessory Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html) to add a UIView above my keyboard. The issue is that the UIView is not displaying at all. Here is my code below:

The header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *accessoryView;

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *editButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;
```

Looking for keyboard notifications:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];

    // observe keyboard hide and show notifications to resize the text view appropriately
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];

    // set the right bar button item initially to "Edit" state
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButton;
}


- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)aTextView {

    // you can create the accessory view programmatically (in code), or from the storyboard
    if (self.textView.inputAccessoryView == nil) {

        self.textView.inputAccessoryView = self.accessoryView;
    }

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.doneButton;

    return YES;
}
```

Finally looking to move the `textField`:

#

```
pragma mark - Responding to keyboard events

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

    /*
     Reduce the size of the text view so that it's not obscured by the keyboard.
     Animate the resize so that it's in sync with the appearance of the keyboard.
     */

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    // Get the origin of the keyboard when it's displayed.
    NSValue *aValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

    // Get the top of the keyboard as the y coordinate of its origin in self's view's
    // coordinate system. The bottom of the text view's frame should align with the top
    // of the keyboard's final position.
    //
    CGRect keyboardRect = [aValue CGRectValue];
    keyboardRect = [self.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil];

    CGFloat keyboardTop = keyboardRect.origin.y;
    CGRect newTextViewFrame = self.view.bounds;
    newTextViewFrame.size.height = keyboardTop - self.view.bounds.origin.y;

    // Get the duration of the animation.
    NSValue *animationDurationValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    [animationDurationValue getValue:&animationDuration];

    // Animate the resize of the text view's frame in sync with the keyboard's appearance.
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];

    self.textView.frame = newTextViewFrame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `self.accessoryView` isn't `nil`?

Comment: How would I fix that? @rmaddy

Comment: Use the debugger or add a log statement.

Comment: Im still getting nothing @rmaddy Im using the same code from the tutorial so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Do you ever assign anything to the `accessoryView` outlet?

Comment: Yes I did but still no result @rmaddy

Comment: did you add the textview e.g. [self addSubview:textview] ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you assigned the IBOutlet accessoryView to an UIView in your storyboard? (That's what they did in the turtorial, too, check the storyboard.) Otherwise it is to be expected, that nothing happens.

Comment: Yes I did but still am not getting any response

Answer (score 0):

Try using a scrollview that will scroll the view up when keyboard appears. To make this easier, try using the [TPKeyboardAvoiding](http://icodetricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/uitextfields-and-keyboard-issues/) library. It is working great, and is very easy to setup:

1. Add a UIScrollView into your view controller's xib
2. Set the scroll view's class to TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView (still
   in the xib, via the identity inspector)
3. Place all your controls within that scrollview

It also automatically hooks up "Next" buttons on the keyboard to switch through the text fields in case you have multiple textfields or textviews.